# Troubles with Kanamori's section on $0^{\sharp}$

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, ordinals, large-cardinals

I am having trouble understanding the following lemma in Kanamori's book. Some notations: $\mathcal{M}(T,\alpha)$ denotes the (unique up to isomorphism) model of $T$ generated by a set of indiscernibles of order type $\alpha$. Here since $T$ preserves well-foundedness $\mathcal{M}(T,\alpha)$ is already identified with some unique $L_\iota$.

[image: Higher Infinite p.105]

Why is the Skolem hull $\mathcal{N}$ literally **equal** to $\mathcal{M}(T,\alpha)$? I understand there is only one **transitive** model isomorphic to $\mathcal{M}(T,\alpha)$, but I cannot see why is $\mathcal{N}$ transitive. From the proof I am somewhat convinced that the transitive collapse of $\mathcal{N}$ has the same height as $\mathcal{N}$, and is equal to $\mathcal{M}(T,\alpha)$, but from the later text it seems we are indeed talking about $\mathcal{N}$ rather than its collapse. So what is the reasoning here?

Also why is $\iota^{T,\alpha}_\xi=\iota^{T,\beta}_\xi$? Is it because they are both indiscernibles generating $\mathcal{M}(T,\alpha)$, and if they were different that would induce a non trivial automorphism of $\mathcal{M}(T,\alpha)$?

A bit of progress: denote the collapse of $\mathcal{N}$ as $\mathcal{N}_0$. The collapse is identity on ordinals. The inverse of the collapsing map is an elementary embedding of $\mathcal{N}_0$ into $\mathcal{M}(T,\alpha)$. It is identity on ordinals. Therefore it seems very plausible to me that it is inclusion, which means the collapse is identity. There are two issues, first I do not know if these models are models of $ZFC$ (they should be; when defining the EM blueprint the author uses the least $\rho$ s.t. $L_{\rho}$ contains an uncountable set of indiscernibles; I wonder if this is the same as the first Erdos cardinal $\kappa(\omega_{1})$). Second issue is that to claim it's inclusion I want to appeal to Proposition 5.1 in the same book, but I am not certain if 5.1 implies that. Another random question: is it impossible for the inclusion between two proper classes to be elementary?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If $\pi\colon M\to L_\alpha$ is an isomorphism which is the identity on the ordinals, then it is the identity: First note that $\pi$ has to be the Mostowski collapse, now suppose that $x\in M$ and $\pi(y)=y$ for all $y\in M$ such that $M\models y\in x$, then $\pi(x)=\{y\in M\mid M\models y\in x\}$. Now since $\pi$ is an isomorphism and the rank function is definable, $\operatorname{rank}(\pi(x))=\pi(\operatorname{rank}(x))$. But by assumption on $\pi$, that must be the same ordinal, so $\pi(x)=x$.

Comment: Alternatively, let $\xi$ be the least rank such that $M$ has a gap (i.e. the first time it is not transitive), and let $x$ be a set such that $\pi(x)$ has rank $\xi$. Because $\pi$ is the identity on the ordinals, the rank of $x$ in $M$ is also $\xi$. Now, if $x\neq\pi(x)$, there is some $y\in x$ such that $y\notin\pi(x)$. But since $x\subseteq M$, this $y\in M$, so $\pi(y)\in\pi(x)$. And this is impossible. (Again, we use the fact that $\pi$ must be the Mostowski collapse.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for your helpful comment Asaf. All these models in the book are elementarily equivalent to $L_{\rho}$, where $\rho$ is the least ordinal s.t. $L_{\rho}$ has an uncountable set of ordinal indiscernibles. How to see directly that such $L_{\rho}$ satisfies ZFC, or at least we can talk about rank?

Comment: Do you mean $\rho=\omega_1^V$? If you already know that $\rho$ is also indiscernible, then it is enough to argue that it is inaccessible in $L$, and therefore $L_\rho$ is a model of ZFC.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I mean the author is working with any EM blueprint that preserves well-foundedness, is cofinal and remarkable. Such a blueprint exists, for example the theory of $L_{\rho}$, where $\rho$ is the least ordinal s.t. blah blah blah. I cannot see why such an EM blueprint must contain axioms of ZFC, or even why this specific $L_{\rho}$ satisfies ZFC.